# Can a roundtable chair not liking my research influence my chances of having a submission accepted?

Tags: conference

I believe that a roundtable chair at an upcoming conference does not like my research. I would like to submit an abstract in response to the call for papers.

Does the roundtable chair play a part in the selection process, or is it solely the task of the conference committee?

Comment: I've given the question a big overhaul to focus on what I think is the essence of your question, but removes the stuff that was probably going to get it closed. Feel free to edit further

Comment: To the OP: You should thank @JeromyAnglim. I was going to vote to close this question  because It had too much personal offence in it. Now, I vote to "Leave Open".

Comment: I will accept the changes but to clarify, the issue is that my research treads on the chair's turf.

Comment: Upon some reflection, you are both right. Neutrality and clarity: my weaknesses; hence, status as an "emerging scholar".

Comment: Some conferences accept all submissions.

Comment: Can you please specify your field? There may be a considerable difference between fields where conferences are the main publication venue (such as computer science) and others. For example, I never encountered the term *roundtable chair* so far.

Comment: I am in the arts and humanities (history)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to anticipate if a roundtable chair will be on the conference's program committee without more information.  Most conferences list their program committee on the conference website.